# Set up Apache 2 to adress ip address and domain name differently

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to set up an apache 2 web server (on Debian) to redirect a user to two different roots. If the user types:

- the ip-address:  12.34.56.78 
                 the server should go to DocumentRoot var/www/link1
- www.mydomain.name
                 the server should go to DocumentRoot var/www/link2
                 (mydomain obviously points to the above ip-address)

I've been trying all kinds of scenario's, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) in Apache, and set the proper `ServerName` parameter . So as per the server name requested, the `VirtualHost` will be picked and configs for that `VirtualHost` will get applied.

Sample Configration will look something like this.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/link1"
    ServerName 12.34.56.78

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/link2"
    ServerName mydomain.name

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

PS: The config above is for Apache Web Server 2.4 and might differ for 2.2, and make sure you have correct permissions for the directories mentioned in `DocumentRoot`